# How to format email to an array - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, email

I need to send a email notification to many users. I loop through and get the users email like this:

```
$userEmails = $favoriteGuides->map(function( $relation ){
      return $relation->users->email;
});
```

And the result is this:

```
Collection {#400 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => "fake@hotmail.com"
    1 => "fake1@hotmail.com"
    2 => "fake3@aol.com"
.... and so on
  ]
}
```

I need to format it so it goes into an array so I can send it into a **Mail** function. It needs to be formatted like this:

```
$emails = ["fake@hotmail.com", "fake2@hotmail.com", "and so on..."];
```

I do I format that into the result I want?

*I already tried  - implode - but that didnt get me the result I wanted.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `toArray()` method:

`$userEmails->toArray();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use toArray() method:

> The toArray method converts the collection into a plain PHP array. If
>   the collection's values are Eloquent models, the models will also be
>   converted to arrays:

So, your code would look like this:

```
$userEmails = $favoriteGuides->map(function( $relation ){
      return $relation->users->email->toArray();
});
```

Comment: Yes ** toArray() ** works. But your method is giving me errors. I tried the method djt did and it works. Thank you though